# C# Sending mail with Yandex error 5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first

Tags: c#, email, sendmail, yandex

I'm having issues sending an email using Yandex.

"SmtpException: Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: 5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first."

I've tried all the solutions from: [C# yandex mail send error 5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391432/c-sharp-yandex-mail-send-error-5-5-4-error-send-auth-command-first)

Solutions I've tried:

- EnableSsl to true
- Changing smtpHost (tried smtp.yandex.com, smtp.yandex.ru, smtp.yandex.com.tr)
- Changing smtpPort (tried 587, 25) (465 doesn't work as SSL deprecated)
- Checked correct password is being used
- Made sure "UseDefaultCredentials = false" is before the credentials being set
- Tried adding in "SMTP.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;"

This is pretty much everything accepted in the above question, however not one solution has worked for me.

**Email Sender Class**

```
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential($"{Configuration["EmailSettings:UserName"]}", $"{Configuration["EmailSettings:Password"]}");
        client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["EmailSettings:SmtpPort"]);
        client.Host = Configuration["EmailSettings:SmtpHost"];
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.EnableSsl = true;


        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress($"{Configuration["EmailSettings:UserName"]}");
        mailMessage.To.Add("SomebodysEmail");
        mailMessage.Body = "body";
        mailMessage.Subject = "subject";
        client.Send(mailMessage);
```

**appsettings.json**

```
"EmailSettings": {
"SmtpHost": "smtp.yandex.com.tr",
"SmtpPort": "25",

"UserName": "email",
"Password": "password"
},
```

In case anyone was curious, I've checked the credentials, port and host are being passed through properly from appsettings.json.

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to `login` into `Mail account` first through the web interface to finish your mailbox `creation`.

This worked in my case with same kind of error.