# How to fix "System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed" in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email, smtp

I'm' trying to send mail from ASP.NET Core 3.1 App, But I always get this error message. How can I fix this?

[I have found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420656/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was-f) similar to this but the answer is 9 years old, it didn't help me.]

```
// Exception e;
// e.Message + e.InnerException + e.GetBaseException() =
Failure sending mail. 
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
The connection was closed. at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, 
Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader 
caller, Boolean oneLine) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller) 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed. 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine) 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller) at 
System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) at 
System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port) at 
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Here is my mail sending code -

```
private void sendmail(string usermail, string message)
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.com", 465);
    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("may mail address", "password");
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.Body = message;
    mail.Subject = "My Awesome Subject";
    mail.From = new MailAddress("may mail address", "Awesome User");
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(usermail));
    smtpClient.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: What about if you try port 587 instead of 465?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change two things as follow and it should work:

1. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20252948/5519709): Try port 587 instead of 465. Port 465 is technically deprecated. `SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.com", 587);`
2. Since you use SSL you need to add: `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`. For more info have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42728008/5519709)

> [**System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) - This property
> selects the version of the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) or Transport
> Layer Security (TLS) protocol to use for new connections that use the
> Secure Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTPS) scheme only; existing
> connections are not changed.

Comment: hi!, now I'm getting a new type of error - System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: 5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first. I have tried to follow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391432/c-sharp-yandex-mail-send-error-5-5-4-error-send-auth-command-first but still getting the error. My password is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yandex has a special password for external applications, so create that password for on the page `https://passport.yandex.ru/profile`. The second point is using the wrong port, it's strange, but Yandex uses 587 instead of 465.

Comment: hi!, now I'm getting a new type of error - System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: 5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first. I have tried to follow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391432/c-sharp-yandex-mail-send-error-5-5-4-error-send-auth-command-first but still getting the error. My password is correct. And tried using app password too.

Comment: Try to change a server URL to ru-related site: `smtp.yandex.ru`.

Comment: It's strange because I copied your code and changed URL and credentials and all work fine. Maybe do you have some network issues?

Comment: Haven't faced any other problems related to internet, so network is pretty stable. I'll give another try and get back to you.